# Trying to extract text from a txt file between 2 symbols and store in a list

Tags: python

EDIT:
Right so the first part of my question has been solved with this nice little piece of code I found online, It has been modified to suit and works a treat, 
The problem I'm having now is making and reading the list that's created, I thought I had made  the list by using lst = [lst] as can be seen at the bottom of the code bellow.
When I run the code bellow it reads the text from the file that is created in the main program and removes everything between [and] and prints it back to me, then I get this output...
['47.660674766635005']

['48.957947570933946']

['49.249363925522836']

['37.88412609655603']

Perfect, except it seems that all 4 strings are made into 1 list and it wont let me choose individual indexes, I've tried using print(lst[0]) which returns the list above but if I change it to lst[1] I get index out of range.
Is it possible to break the list down even further??
Tried all sorts of configurations with indexes for lists, been through the man pages and I've tried all of that, Must be close
Tried making a list of lists but still having the same problems.

So it would seem to me the obvious answer would be to look to the point where the string has been found in the text file then add it to a list straight away before searching,
Tried a few things like create a new list and have the code that searches then append() to the list but no, Still problems.

Tried for x in lst() and added an x to the start of each string, Then Create a list.
This option I think might be the best because to work out the average of all the mpg's, I will need to know how many indexes there are in the list to divide the numbers by. I'll just get it to count the X's
There's probably an easier way but I'm not sure.
Just been reading the json manpage that was linked bellow and that seems like a good option. Looks technical I'll have to have a play around with that

Any clues please anybody

```
file_path = '/home/jon/Desktop/mpg.txt'

#Open the file in read mode. with operator is used to take care of try..except..finally block.
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    '''Read the contents of file. Be careful here as this will read the entire file into memory. 
       If file is too large prefer iterating over file object
    '''
    #count=0
    content = f.read()
    size = len(content)
    start =0
    while start < size:
        # Read the starting index of & after the last [ index.
        start = content.find("[",start)
        # If found, continue else go to end of contents (this is just to avoid writing if statements.
        start = start if start != -1 else size
        # Read the starting index of ! after the last ] index.
        end = content.find("]", start)
        # Again, if found, continue else go to end of contents (this is just to avoid writing if statements.
        end = end if end != -1 else size
        '''print the contents between [ and ] (excluding both these operators. 
           If no ! character is found, print till the end of file.
        '''

        lst = content[start+1:end] 
        lst = [lst]
        start = end + 1
        print(lst)
```

Scratching away lol, I'll get there in the end

```
============== Original Question Bellow ===========
```

I've made a little program that works out my miles per gallon and writes the results to a text file. It might not be the neatest code but I'm learning,

In the def writeToFile() function I have cast the mpg into a list just before it is written to the file, the program doesn't actually use the list, That's just there because I thought it might make it easier to extract the data between [ and ] from the txt file later.
As you can see in this example from the output in the text file the mpg is surrounded by []

```
 Your mpg is...

[37.88412609655603]
```

What I would like to be able to do is read through the text file that the program creates and copy anything between [ and ].
The function that controls that is defined as `averageMiles()`, I have left in and commented out some of the code I've tried, I've also tried a few other things but nothing works as I'd like. 
I know I'm close but just can't quite get the last bit,

When I have managed to read the text file and extract all the mpg data into a new list I will then make it work out an average for all the mpg and print to the screen or to a file so the data must be readable.

If someone could just give me a point in the right direction instead of the answer that would be great.
I'm using Python 3.3.2 Ubuntu

```
import time
import os, sys
GALLON = float(0.219969)
TIME = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
DATE = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
print('enter litres...')
litre = input()
litre = float(litre)
gallonsUsed = litre * GALLON
print('Enter miles')
milesDriven = input()
milesDriven = float(milesDriven)
mpg = milesDriven / gallonsUsed
print('You\'re current mpg is \n  '+str(mpg)+'')
#mpg = [mpg]

def averageMiles():
    file_path = 'mpg.txt'
    with open(file_path, "r") as f: 
        content = f.read()
        size = len(content)
        start =0
        while start < size:
            start = content.find("[",start)
            start = start if start != -1 else size
            end = content.find("]", start)
            end = end if end != -1 else size
            print(content[start+1:end])
            start = end + 1



def checkFile():
    if os.path.isfile('mpg.txt') == True:
        writeToFile()
    else:
        print('File does not exist')
        print('   Making File')
        open("mpg.txt", 'w')
        writeToFile()

def writeToFile():
    file = open("mpg.txt", "r")
    filedata = file.read()
    file.close()

    newLine = " ====================== \n     Your mpg is...\n ---------------------- \n  "+str([mpg])+"   \n ---------------------- \n   Time - "+str(TIME)+" \n   Date - "+str(DATE)+" \n ====================== \n \n" + filedata
    file = open("mpg.txt", "w")
    file.write(newLine)
    #outfile.write("\n".join(mpg))
    file.close()

    file = open("mpg.txt", "r")
    filedata = file.read()
    file.close()
    averageMiles()
    print(filedata)
#averageMiles()
checkFile()
```

EDIT: Tidied up the post to try make question clearer, Just read it again and it didn't make sense

EDIT: I have figured out how to get the string back from the text file, next just need to make it into something I can use, Going to try make it into a list, from then I can use whatever maths to work out the average mpg. I need to learn some maths next then lol.
Here is the code so far, I have already appended it to the main code, so far it should all run as planned
Thanks for your suggestions, I will post the rest of the code when I get it finished

```
def averageMiles():
    file_path = 'mpg.txt'
    with open(file_path, "r") as f: 
        content = f.read()
        size = len(content)
        start =0
        while start < size:
            start = content.find("[",start)
            start = start if start != -1 else size
            end = content.find("]", start)
            end = end if end != -1 else size
            print(content[start+1:end])
            start = end + 1
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? At what point in your code does something stop working as expected?

Comment: No not getting errors with the code, just trying to add a new function that reads the txt file the program has outputted, and then copies all the numbers between [ and ] and then maybe creates a list or something that I can then use to do an average mpg from all the entries in the txt file, Then output to screen, just not sure the best way to do it, I've learnt a bit about lists but obviously not enough to solve this lol

Comment: Well, why don't you read the file line-by-line (`for line in file`) and try using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on it (be sure to catch `ValueError`s). If you get a python object from it, check to see if it's a `list`. That could be a start for you.

Comment: Sorry if the title was miss leading didn't realise you can't use [ ]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You could write whatever you like in the file. `ast.literal_eval` will read a string and see if it can make it into a python literal object. e.g. `ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')` will give you the list `[1, 2, 3]`. So if you were putting your different measurements into the file by casting them into a string, you could read it back out like that.

Comment: I see, just had a little read up about ast.literal_eval, In the program the list isn't created until the text is written to the txt file. The program doesn't actually use the list, I just thought I would do that thinking it might make it easier to extract all data between [ ] later on. I see what your saying though, so [ ] can be read as a list from the text file all I have to do is set the right parameters with ast.literal. Thanks

Comment: It's just one way to try to solve this problem. You could also try to use a well-established format for storing data like [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) or [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in the first place instead. Pick an approach and if you run into trouble update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after much head scratching I have changed my approach and gone for this instead

```
lompg = str('newlist.txt')


mpgList = open(lompg, "r")
listData = mpgList.read()
mpgList.close()
listData=listData.split()
listLength = (len(listData))
data = sum(map(float, listData))
avg = data /listLength
print(avg)
```

I'ts not quite what I wanted but it does the job, What I have done is made it so a seperate text file is created that stores just the mpg figures, that file is then read back when it calculates the average mpg.
Finished code if anyone wants it, runs in python 3.3.2
To run save the code bellow to a file and then cd to location file is stored, then python3 'filename.py' all files created by program will be made in that location

```
import time
import os
outfile = 'mpgoutput.txt' # record of mpg results
infile = 'mpglist.txt' # list of all mpg to calculate avg
GALLON = float(0.219969) # 1 litre, used to calculate litres into gallons
TIME = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
DATE = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
print('enter litres...')
litre = input()
litre = float(litre)
gallonsUsed = litre * GALLON # work out litres into gallons
print('Enter miles')
milesDriven = input()
milesDriven = float(milesDriven)
mpg = milesDriven / gallonsUsed # mpg calculated
if os.path.isfile(infile) == False: # check if file exists if not create it
     print('File does not exist')
     print('   Making File')
     open(infile, 'w')
mpglistread = open(infile, "r") 
originalList = mpglistread.read()
mpglistread.close()
mpglistwrite = open(infile, "w")
mpglistwrite.write(''+str(mpg)+'\n' + originalList) 
mpglistwrite.close()
mpgList = open(infile, "r")
listData = mpgList.read()
mpgList.close()
listData=listData.split()
listLength = (len(listData))
data = sum(map(float, listData))
avg = data /listLength

def checkFile():
    if os.path.isfile(outfile) == True:
        readFile()
    else:
        print('File does not exist')
        print('   Making File')
        open(outfile, 'w')
        readFile()

def readFile():

    file = open(outfile, "r")
    filedata = file.read()
    file.close()
    newLine = " ====================== \n     Your mpg is...\n ---------------------- \n  "+str([mpg])+"   \n ---------------------- \n   Time - "+str(TIME)+" \n   Date - "+str(DATE)+" \n ====================== \n \n" + filedata
    file = open(outfile, "w")
    file.write(newLine)
    file.close()
    file = open(outfile, "r")
    filedata = file.read()
    file.close()
    print('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n') 
    print(" ====================== \n     Your mpg is...\n ++++++++++++++++++++++ \n  "+str([mpg])+"   \n ---------------------- \n Your average mpg is...\n ++++++++++++++++++++++ \n  "+str(avg)+"   \n ---------------------- \n   Time - "+str(TIME)+" \n   Date - "+str(DATE)+" \n ====================== \n \n")

checkFile()
```